# Unwanteed period added to "in" when making a JSON from data frame (R jsonlite)

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

When generating a JSON object from a data frame in R, "in" is converted to "in." and I'm not sure how to solve this. Any help would be appreciated!

```
library(jsonlite)

query_json3 <- data.frame("eClass" = c("Fermentation","Sample", "ResultValue","Experiment"), 
                         "collection" = c("fermentations","samples", "resultValues", "experiments"))
filters1 <- data.frame("field" = "attributes.experiment", 
                      "value" = "EXP-EB-22-019")
filters2 <- data.frame("field" = "originID", 
                       "in" = "fermentations.originID")
filters3 <- data.frame("field" = "SubjectID", 
                       "in" = "samples.id")
filters4 <- data.frame("field" = "type", 
                       "value" = "Small-Scale Screening")

query_json3[1, "filters"][[1]] <- list(filters1)
query_json3[2, "filters"][[1]] <- list(filters2)
query_json3[3, "filters"][[1]] <- list(filters3)
query_json3[4, "filters"][[1]] <- list(filters4)

toJSON(query_json3)
```

Output:

```
[{"eClass":"Fermentation","collection":"fermentations","filters":[{"field":"attributes.experiment","value":"EXP-EB-22-019"}]},{"eClass":"Sample","collection":"samples","filters":[{"field":"originID","in.":"fermentations.originID"}]},{"eClass":"ResultValue","collection":"resultValues","filters":[{"field":"SubjectID","in.":"samples.id"}]},{"eClass":"Experiment","collection":"experiments","filters":[{"field":"type","value":"Small-Scale Screening"}]}]
```

Desired output:

```
[{"eClass":"Fermentation","collection":"fermentations","filters":[{"field":"attributes.experiment","value":"EXP-EB-22-019"}]},{"eClass":"Sample","collection":"samples","filters":[{"field":"originID","in":"fermentations.originID"}]},{"eClass":"ResultValue","collection":"resultValues","filters":[{"field":"SubjectID","in":"samples.id"}]},{"eClass":"Experiment","collection":"experiments","filters":[{"field":"type","value":"Small-Scale Screening"}]}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smoking gun is not **jsonlite** here. `in` is a reserved keyword in R, and for this reason, `data.frame` adds the period. You can use `check.names=FALSE`:

```
data.frame("field" = "SubjectID", 
           "in" = "samples.id")
#       field        in.
# 1 SubjectID samples.id
data.frame("field" = "SubjectID", 
           "in" = "samples.id", 
           check.names = FALSE)
#       field         in
# 1 SubjectID samples.id
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not actually to do with jsonlite. If you look at your dataframe `filters3` then you can see that the column name has changed already there so jsonlite is doing exactly what it should. There are reserved words in R (see for example here: https://learnetutorials.com/r-programming/identifiers-constants-reserved-words) and "in" is a reserved word. Can you change the name of this field without breaking things elsewhere? If the name is causing problems here then it is likely to cause problems elsewhere too.